# How to evaluate number of security bits of a signature scheme?

Tags: signature, provable-security, post-quantum-cryptography, security-definition, hash-signature

I am trying to evaluate the effective security levels that a digital signature scheme (namely post-quantum digital schemes like WOT-S (Winternitz one time signature scheme) and Dilithium Crystals). How should I do that for a particular message?

For WOT-S I am using the standard python library For Dilithium I am using Liboqs Library.

- For WOT-S I referred to the following research paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225630354_On_the_Security_of_the_Winternitz_One-Time_Signature_Scheme. The formula for security level gives me a value of 405. Which I feel is not right.
- For Dilithium I was not able to find a paper that quotes any formula for it.